# Regular expression to match numeric strings and newlines in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I've been trying to write a regular expression that matches numeric string and newlines like:

```
"47832748973284793\r\n321321321321\r\n423423432432423432".match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(_?\d+)*(\.\d+e?\d*)?\Z/) == nil ? false : true
```

it will return false because of '\r\n', in fact, it should match '\r\n' as well.

can someone help me to achieve it ?

Comment: Why do you want to match `-+`? are you parsing numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your pattern defines a single number, then you have to add the "special case" as following group but additionally with the the part that differs from the original pattern, the `\r\n`

```
"47832748973284793\r\n321321321321\r\n423423432432423432".match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(_?\d+)*(\.\d+e?\d*)?(\r\n[+-]?\d+?(_?\d+)*(\.\d+e?\d*)?)*\Z/) == nil ? false : true
                                                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and let that special part repeat 0 or more times.

prints out:

```
irb(main):005:0> text  
=> "47832748973284793\r\n321321321321\r\n423423432432423432"  
irb(main):007:0> text.match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(_?\d+)*(\.\d+e?\d*)?(\r\n[+-]?\d+?(_?\d+)*(\.\d+e?\d*)?)*\Z/) == nil ? false : true  
=> true
```